# Cannot convert from 'Models.ApplicationUser' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, identity

I have one problem and I try to solve it but unsuccessful. I will try to explain what is the problem.
I use `ASP.NET CORE 5.0 MVC` `EntityFramework` and `IdentityModel` to create application for Ticket System (Help Desk).
Once I notice that EntityFramework store `UserID` as string I change this to `INT`

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser<int>, IdentityRole<int>, int>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
   
    }
}
```

And In my `ApplicationUser.cs` Model I change to

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>
    {
        
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Ime")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Adresa")]
        public string StreetAddress { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Grad")]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Postanski broj")]
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }

        public int? ClientId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ClientId")]
        public Client Client { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public string Role { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> RoleList { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ClientList { get; set; }
    }
```

And in `Startup.cs`

From this

```
 services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser,IdentityRole>().AddDefaultTokenProviders()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

To

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser<int>,IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Right now I have problem in my UserController where I get error message

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Models.ApplicationUser' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser'

[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(ApplicationUser user, Client client)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var objFromDb = _db.ApplicationUsers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == user.Id);


                if (objFromDb == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }

                var userRole = _db.UserRoles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserId == objFromDb.Id);



                if (userRole != null)
                {
                    var previousRoleName = _db.Roles.Where(u => u.Id == userRole.RoleId).Select(e => e.Name).FirstOrDefault();
                    await _userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(objFromDb //<-- here I get error, previousRoleName);
                }


                await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(objFromDb //<-- here I get error, _db.Roles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id.ToString() == user.Role).Name);
                objFromDb.Name = user.Name;
                objFromDb.Email = user.Email;
                objFromDb.PhoneNumber = user.PhoneNumber;
                objFromDb.StreetAddress = user.StreetAddress;
                objFromDb.City = user.City;
                objFromDb.PostalCode = user.PostalCode;
                objFromDb.RoleList = user.RoleList;
                objFromDb.ClientId = user.ClientId;
                _db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }

            user.RoleList = _db.Roles.Select(u => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = u.Name,
                Value = u.Id.ToString()
            });

            user.ClientList = _db.Clients.Select(u => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = u.Name,
                Value = u.Id.ToString()
            });

            return View(user);
        }
```

Once I try to figure out where the problem is, I can not find what I missing here. I try to google but mostly post is not releated to this once which I need. Also here in stackoverflow but I can not find solution. Anyone who can tell me what is wrong here ? What do I need to change ?

Comment: Try ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser
You may also need a custom applicationrole

Comment: @paul where to put this line of code ?

Comment: In the dbcontect against the interface. Instead of identity user

Comment: @paul I have alredy try this. but doesn't work.

Comment: public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<int>, int>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
   
    }
} So like this?

Comment: Yes, I try. Doesn't work !

Answer (score 1):

Identity registration is not done properly. you may need to register `IdentityUser` to `ApplicationUser` like this:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser,IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Comment: `IdentityRle<int>`?